# How do I interact with `req$postBody` in a plumber API?

Tags: r, plumber

My team is moving a model to production and we really like the new [vetiver](https://github.com/rstudio/vetiver-r) package. Sending a json object to the predict end point works great, but we'd like to perform some checks on the request body and augment the request with data before sending it to the prediction endpoint. The problem is that we aren't able to interact with `req$postBody` in a meaningful manner.

So far we've tried converting converting the request using `jsonlite::fromJSON(req$postBody)` inside of a filter endpoint, tried interacting directly with request such as `ncol(req$postBody)`, and other similar approaches.

```
library(plumber)
library(vetiver)

cars_lm <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
v <- vetiver_model(cars_lm, "cars_linear")

augment_data <- data.frame(
  'extra_1' = 4,
  'extra_2' = 2
)

pr() %>% 
  pr_filter("/dim", function(req) {cat(ncol(req$postBody)); plumber::forward()}) %>%
  pr_filter("/augment", function(req) {req$postBody <- cbind(req$postBody, augment_data)); plumber::forward()}) %>%
  vetiver_api(v) %>%
  pr_run()
```